# Launch an EXE with elevated privileges from a "normal" non-elevated one?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, privileges

I have an EXE running with normal privileges, but there are cases (for example using VSS / volume shadow copy) where I need admin privileges (if I'm not mistaken)

The idea is to put the code that needs extra privileges in a separate EXE and launch it as needed.

It's something that I'll rarely need, but I still need to have it as a last resort option (this is to say that I'll rarely need to call it, maybe once/twice a day on average)

**My question is: How can I call an admin-elevated process from a normal EXE?**

Comment: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs
function RunAsAdmin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Vista and later with UAC enabled, the best option is to provide the second EXE with a UAC manifest (preferrably embedded as a resource, but can also be done with an external .manifest file) that sets the `requestedExecutionLevel` value to `requireAdministrator`.  Then you can just `CreateProcess()` the EXE file normally.  If providing a manifest is not an option, or if you need to support XP and/or non-UAC setups, then you can use `ShellExecute/Ex()` specifying the `"runas"` verb instead.  Under any of these setups, the OS will prompt the user for permission and account credentials, and then apply the appropriate security rights to the new process as needed.

Another option is the third-party `CreateProcess...Elevated()` (and `ShellExecute...Elevated()`) implementations provided in this article:

[Vista UAC: The Definitive Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide)

Comment: Thank you Remy, if I added a manifest, would I be able to run without prompting the user? Prompting user everytime I have to call VSS is very annoying, esp. that my application is supposed to run silently without disturbing the user

Comment: @TheDude: When a manifest is present, it is applied at the time the EXE is first started. If the EXE is run from another non-elevated process, a UAC prompt is displayed asking for permission. This is desired behavior. If you do not want to prompt each time, then you need to elevate the calling process, which will likely mean re-thinking your design. If you do not want to elevate your main app, then you may need to move your VSS access to a background service instead, and then have your main app communicate with it when needed.

Comment: Thanks, yes that goes well with my ultimate goal (running the EXE itself as a service), but I've never went this road because I wasn't familiar with services, much less with debugging them! I guess now it's time to do this only I'm not sure how to proceed :(

Comment: @TheDude: Start with `File > New > Other > Delphi Projects > Service Application`. That will create a stub service that you can then expand on as needed. There are plenty of demos and tutorials available for writing services in Delphi.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Just as an remark: As i seen, M$ applied security only for PF and Win folders. If i installs my program into, for example, c:\myprg\p, there are no any restriction. It was very useful for my customers - no any constraints for work :)